# Is system name must identical with file name when do asdf:load-system?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I am learning ASDF but encountered strange issue when do loading the defined system. Here are some information.
i defined a .asd file named "hello.asd" with a single line content:

```
(asdf:defsystem :hellosystem)
```

and i put this file into a directory called "**/tmp/pkg**". After that, i run SBCL and try to load it. Here is the output:

```
This is SBCL 1.1.12, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (asdf:asdf-version)

"3.0.2"
* (push #P"/tmp/pkg/" asdf:*central-registry*)

(#P"/tmp/pkg/" #P"/Users/wuli2/quicklisp/quicklisp/")
* (asdf:load-system :hellosystem)

debugger invoked on a ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM:MISSING-COMPONENT:
  Component :HELLOSYSTEM not found

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE (SYMBOL T)) ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :HELLOSYSTEM) [fast-method]
0] 0

* (asdf:load-system :hello)

debugger invoked on a ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM:MISSING-COMPONENT:
  Component :HELLO not found

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE (SYMBOL T)) ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :HELLO) [fast-method]
0] 0

* (asdf:load-system :hellosystem)

T
*
```

Please be noted, the first time i tried to load system **:hellosystem**, it failed. So i load the system **:hello**, i gussed maybe it need a filename, it failed again. The weired thing happened when i occasionally run load system **:hellosystem** again, it worked.

So i made another test, change the file name to let it same as system name. Then run asdf:load-system, it worked directly.

It confused me very much, i cannot find any clue in ASDF manual that the two names should be identical?

Could somebody give me some insight on it?

Thanks,

Wu

Answer (score 3):

I found this clue: "*Note the name of a system is specified as a string or a symbol, typically a keyword. If a symbol (including a keyword), its name is taken and lowercased. The name must be a suitable value for the :name initarg to make-pathname in whatever filesystem the system is to be found.*"

http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Using-ASDF.html

The message is that an `(asdf:defsystem <symbol> ...)` form should reside in a file called `<lowercased-symbol>.asd`.  If you name the system with a string, the file name should use that string.

Comment: From my understanding to it, when do loading the system, if a symbol is given, we must defined system with lower cased name, and must make file name same as the name. Is it correct?  But i have still no idea why after i called asdf:load-system hello, then call asdf:load-system hello system works.

Comment: @WuLi When you tried to load the system named `hello`, ASDF loaded a file named "hello.asd", where you define the system `hellosystem` (at this point, ASDF knows that `hellosystem` is a defined system-definition) and then when you tried loading `hellosystem` the system exists and everyone is happy. For some value of "happy".

Comment: ah, a strange behaviour that ASDF remembered what he detected. I just like  using keyword as a system or package name, seems i need make loading system name, file name and defined system name identical.